# Duplicate case is created after making changes in closed won stage

Tags: process-builder, case

I have created a process to create a case automatically after closed won, but I don't want to make another case if I go back in different stage in opportunity and select closed won again.

Answer (score 1):

If, as part of the process, you were to set a flag, you could use that to prevent the record from being created again. Or, you could use a Flow or Apex to identify if the record has already been created, in order to avoid the duplicate. In other words, there are ways to avoid this, but you'll need to implement some additional logic.